# onMessageSend Launch event showing error when deployed in organization

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I created a outlook addin that has the onMessageSend launch event.
I tested it by installing manually using the file (manifest.xml) in outlook and the launchevent worked fine.
I deployed the addin in an org, Now the addin Shows the prompt while sending any message.
"Addin is unavailable and cannot process your request at this time".

I am not getting what's the problem.
I have tested the addin by installing the manifest.xml manually in windows and mac, and didn't get any error.
But When I deploy it in org and use the addin, the prompt comes. Please help.

I tried deploying the addin in organization,
Expected Outcome: The onMessageSend launchevent should Work fine without showing any prompt.
Actualy Outcome: Show prompt evertime a message is sent
"Addin is unavailable and cannot process your request at this time"

When I tried to install it individually and use it, the launch event works fine

Answer (score 0):

> "Addin is unavailable and cannot process your request at this time".

This indicates that add-in files are not reachable on the client. On-send add-ins will run according to the online state of the user, the add-in backend, and Exchange. An on-send add-in will run if its backend is online and reachable. If the backend is offline, send is disabled.

I'd suggest trying to load the add-in files after deploying the add-in from the web browser and try to check dev tools when a web browser is used.